# How to create a thumbnail image of html content stored in a database

Tags: javascript, html, screen-scraping, rendering

If you were to **convert this html content into a small thumbnail image** , how would you do it?

P.S. I'm trying to do this to allow users on my site to browse through their posts(containing html elements (e.g. strong, i, img tag's).

Comment: it is not called "converting", but it's "rendering". and you need a browser-like application to do it. this question has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: Hey thanks, i was thinking maybe the PHP GD library could just be tweaked to behave in a superhuman, perhap's i'm wrong. How do you suggest i go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

http://www.thumbalizr.com/index.php

They have a pretty decent simple API

> Simple syntax to use the API:
>   http://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=http://www.ford.de&width=250
>
> Parameter:
>
> Check http://api.thumbalizr.com for
>   more details.

So you can simply have `<img src='http://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=http://www.yourdomain.com&width=250' />`

Also see http://www.websnapr.com/ and their [implementations page](http://www.websnapr.com/implementations/)

Comment: How can i use one of these on my local server, these seem to be one's to be used on the web.

Answer (score 1):

try http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/website-thumbnail-generator.php